# Jni calling java function from c++

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

This google function gets called on cclayers like pause etc with the view name
 analyticsInterface.cpp

```
void analyticsInterface::google (std::string x){
JniMethodInfo t;

if (JniHelper::getMethodInfo(t,
 "com.pathto.MainActivity",
 "ganalyiticscall",
 "(Ljava/lang/String;I;)V;")) {

   char* myName = "root view";
  int times = 3;

 jstring stringArg1 = t.env->NewStringUTF(myName);
 t.env->CallVoidMethod(t.classID,
     t.methodID,
   stringArg1);

 t.env->DeleteLocalRef(t.classID);
 t.env->DeleteLocalRef(stringArg1);
}}
```

trying to call this function via the cpp as the main activity doesn't know what layer is active.

mainacivity.java

```
public void ganalyiticscall(String ScreenName){
    GoogleAnalytics mGaInstance = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    Tracker t = mGaInstance.newTracker("UA-xxxxx-1");
    Log.i("call from ganal","tracker made");
        // Set screen name.
    t.setScreenName(ScreenName);

    // Send a screen view.
    t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
}
```

Comment: Do you have a MainActivity instance to call it on? What you're trying now is the equivalent of `((MainActivity)"root view").ganalyiticscall();` in Java.

Comment: "(Ljava/lang/String;I;)V;" suggests the method takes two parameters, a String and an int. But you're only passing a single String argument. That seems like a bad idea.

Comment: ya not so familiar with uni here never really used it before. but to give more context I have a cocos2d game and trying to get the cclayers to pass what "view" they are to the java function for google analytics